# Controlling the fill of a rect through CSS in Raphael

Tags: javascript, css, svg, raphael

I am using Raphael and I want to create a rect and control the fill property through a CSS.

Everything works fine when I set the fill attr in the classical way:

```
    space = paper.rect(0,0,1000,500).attr({fill: "url('img/cell_background.png')"});
```

In fact, with this approach I get the correct filling. If inspect the elements I can see that in the `rect` element the `fill` attribute is specified and it refers to a pattern defined in the `svg`'s `defs`.

```
<svg>
   ...
   <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); ">
        <pattern style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " 
         id="E6992022-9B75-4D1E-9D44-6EC45CE420A1" x="0" y="0" 
         patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="5" width="9" 
         patternTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(0,0)">
           <image style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " 
                      x="0" y="0" 
                  href="img/cell_background.png" width="9" height="5">
               </image>
        
            </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); " 
        x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="500" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" 
    fill="url(#E6992022-9B75-4D1E-9D44-6EC45CE420A1)" stroke="#000" 
    class="space">
      </rect>
    ...
</svg>
```

If I instead create the `rect` with the following code:

```
space = paper.rect(0,0,1000,500);
space.node.setAttribute("class","space");
```

And then in the .css I define:

```
.space {
fill: url('img/cell_background.png');
stroke: #ff0000;
}
```

Then the inspected html shows a `fill='none'` as `rect` attribute, the rectangle is correctly rendered with a red border, but it is filled with a solid black.

Some further observations:

1. js are in the js/ folder, css in css/ folder, and images in img/ folder. I tried with '../img', './img' and 'img' but I have the same behaviour;
2. if I don't put fill I obtain a white filling as expected;
3. if I put `fill: foobar` I obtain a white background;
4. if I put `fill: #ff0000` I get the expected red background;
5. I obtain the same black background if I use a fake filename;
6. the behaviour is consistent with Chrome and with Firefox.

From the fourth and fifth point it looks like the file cannot be found, but I think to have exhausted the combination of paths that I should have checked (the css finds other images in the same folder using the '../img' path). I reckon that the problem is somewhere else.

Does anybody had a similar experience?

Comment: You're trying to use CSS to set the attributes of SVG elements?

Comment: Yes. Is that utterly wrong? Since it is working with the stroke I naively thought it could work with the fill as well. Silly me!

Comment: I checked you can use CSS on SVG: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS

Comment: The url should be relative to the CSS file so ../img would seem to be right. Are you running this locally or in a web server as you may be running into local file access security restrictions. Is there anything in the browser error console?

Comment: It is run locally, as I said the image is correctly displayed if I don't use the css, I don't think is a permission problem. On the Firefox web console I can't see any error or warning related to those lines. I cannot see any request for that image.

Comment: Why don't you temporarily stick everything in the same directory. That would determine whether you've got a permissions issue or not.

Comment: I've put everything in a single .html (with css in the CDATA, and the code in a script tag), and the image in the same directory. Same behaviour: it works using the .attr and I get the black fill using the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG you can't just specify a bitmap background url for an element as you do with HTML elements. The standard way of doing this in SVG is through `pattern` definitions. Raphael abstracts this messiness from you with a simple `fill: url(...)`.

You could load the pattern with your CSS stylesheet with something like...

```
.space {
  fill: url('img/cell_background.svg#bitmap');
  stroke: #ff0000;
}
```

But of course, `cell_background.svg#bitmap` still needs to look like...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
        <pattern id="bitmap" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="5" width="9">
           <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="img/cell_background.png" width="9" height="5">
           </image>
         </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

But of course this only makes matters more complex.

The reason why your rect is showing up black is because the engine is trying to load a missing fill definition (gradient or pattern), which defaults to black.

Comment: I tried but it does not seems to work. I still have the black filling. And there is no request from the browser to get cell_background.svg.

Comment: To be more precise the previous test was done in Chrome, in Firefox I get a white filling.

Comment: Gah, I forgot you need to add `xlink` as in `xlink:href="img/cell_background.png"` (answer updated). But even then I'm seeing Webkit doesn't allow loading external defs. What are you tryign to accomplish that Raphael doesn't provide?

Comment: It works on Firefox, still unlucky on chrome. What I would like to obtain is to style everything from css (I would prefer the web designer not touching the js). I can anyway create a simple js file with just info about shapes backgrounds. I've read on other posts of the idiosyncrasy of some browser for external defs. Thanks for the help.